# combine two or more string arrays

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find the fastest way to concatenate row values from about 7 columns, from huge files(800 000 rows).

I found an almost instant way of loading each column in separate arrays.

But when I use the code below, the processing is very slow, like 2-3 seconds for each 100 rows.

Maybe you guys can help me with a way to concatenate values from parallel arrays without a for.

The columns are not in the correct order.

```
For rowI = LBound(arrShInvoice) To UBound(arrShInvoice)
    dKey = arrShInvoice(rowI, 1)
    dItem = ""

    Call displayStatusBarEvents("Procesing " & dFName & vbNewLine & "row: ", rowI, UBound(arrShInvoice), 100, , True)
    For Each colI In arrTargetFields
        If dItem = "" Then
            dItem = dData(colI)(rowI, 1)
        Else
            dItem = dItem & delimiterI & dData(colI)(rowI, 1)
        End If
    Next
    dDescriptive.Add dKey, dItem
Next
```

I'm fairly advanced with VBA so hit my with your best ideas.

Comment: Just a rando thought - have you tried to write     `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` before starting the loops? I saw that you need speed... And remove the `displayStatusBarEvents`, it probably slows you down as well.

Comment: Also, what type is `dData`?

Comment: Obviously, a perf wrap with the classics (EnableEvents, ...). Which App of MsOffice are you using? Can you add a bit more of your code (Declaration and filling/splitting arrays) and describe your arrays, because it looks like your are doing arrays of arrays, it'd be best to explain us! ;)

Comment: How advanced is "fairly advanced"?  You can probably do this by hacking the underlying safearrays and manually appending the 2 arrays' data areas, but that involves some fairly hardcore memory management.

Comment: What would you consider good performance?

Comment: My bad,  I should have giving you guys more details.
There are 2 helpful macros that I use each time(also in this case):
1. One turns on at the begining and on at the end, the following:           With Application
                .EnableEvents = False
                .DisplayAlerts = False
                .Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'xlAutomatic=-4105  xlManual=-4135
                .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
2. A macro that displays status (row X/Total rows) and runs a DoEvents every Y number of rows.
Variables starting with "d" are dictionaries, "arr" arrays

Comment: I am getting the columns into arrays like this:
dKey = HeaderName
dItem = .Range(.Cells(HeaderRow + 1, targetCol), .Cells(lastRow, targetCol)).Value2 
dTemp.Add dKey, dItem    'in this case dItem and dKey are not dictionary, are actually the keys and items

Comment: The main purpose is to compare 1 file with several others. All have a unique identifier, and I need to bring the Concatenated fields into the main file, and check for duplicates. If anyone can give me some ideas on how to streamline the process, i would really appreciated. I need to find a way because of the large amount of data!

Comment: Is there a quick way to join parallel arrays, like Array("a","b","c") and Array(1,2,3) and get array(A1, B2, C3) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult as your post is general, and we haven't seen the full code (would be good to see it!). Will add this as answer given it doesn't suit a set of comments

You must read [Optimize string handling in VB6](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt.html)

1. When concatenating, join the longs strings once. `dItem & (delimiterI & dData(colI)(rowI, 1))` is much superior to  `dItem & delimiterI & dData(colI)(rowI, 1)` which uses `Ditem` twice
2. `VbNullString` or `Len(Ditem) = 0` is quicker than `If dItem = ""`
3. Your `IF`test should branch to the more likely outcome first to avoid going via `Else`. If *dItem* is not likely to be blank, change your `IF` flow
4. If you must have a progress indicator, use the `StatusBar` every 10000 rows or so (using *Mod*) rather than call a separate function (which you are doing *each* line)

*your new question*

Short of using PowerShell you will have to combine your arrays with a `For` loop, ie

```
Dim Array1()
Dim Array2()
Dim lngRow As Long

Array1 = Array("a", "b", "c")
Array2 = Array(1, 2, 3)

For lngRow = 0 To UBound(Array1)
    Array1(lngRow) = Array1(lngRow) & Array2(lngRow)
Next
```